# How to pause/sleep() function without crashing app?

Tags: python, multithreading, function, time, sleep

I have an app I'm trying to add website updates to every minute. That part works just fine at the moment. The problem I'm experiencing with this current excerpt of code is that, when I go to close/exit the app, I have to hit the "X" button a few times and it completely crashes and freezes.

If my understanding is correct, I believe that is happening because `time.sleep()` is still "running" constantly when I try to exit.

How can I run a regular update like this that wont throw the app into a fit when I want to close it? Can someone please help me with a solution here?

I have added just a 5 second sleep in this working example here instead of my intended 60 seconds to save time when you test it.

```
import time
from threading import Thread
from kivy.app import App

class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        self.thread_for_update()

    def thread_for_update(self):
        p1 = Thread(target=lambda: self.check_for_update())
        p1.start()

    def check_for_update(self):
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Update")
        # Here I'm checking an online data source for changes
        # I will also notify user if theres changes
        self.thread_for_update()
Test().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have fixed it. when I add `p1.daemon = True` it seems to exit the program well when I try to exit.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `threading.Timer`, and update it in another function.

`threading.Timer` takes 2 argument, the delay (in seconds) and the function to call.

```py
def check_for_update(self):
        Timer(5, self.update).start()
        

def update(self):
        print("Update")
        self.thread_for_update()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried your method and also tried running it in different ways with and without threading but it still seems to be freaking out when I close the app. Is it something to do with threading maybe?